# flash/html, how to embed a flash movie so that it scales with the browser window

Tags: html, flash

i would like to show my flash movie in a browser window so that it fills width and height as good as possible without distorting the movie.

when i use the width and height attribute to the object/embed tags it only scales the width but not the height.

```
  <body bgcolor="#000000" 
        width="100%"
        height="100%">
    <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
            codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0"            
            width="100%"
            height="100%"
            align=""
            id="slot">
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="movie" value="..." />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="width" value="100%" />
        <param name="height" value="100%" />
        <embed src="..."
            width="100%" height="100%" quality="high" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="true" wmode="opaque" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
    </object>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add some CSS to the HTML page:

```
html, body { height: 100% }
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work is youset the **width** and **height** to 100%. Then set the **scalemode** to **showAll**, that should prevent the movie from distorting.

Then you could of course set the css padding and margin of the html body to 0px the get the most area of the window.

Answer (score 0):

Use **[swffit](http://swffit.millermedeiros.com/)**. It resizes flash when the browser window is changed.